# xcode: Does CALayer erase (blank) its previous image when I change its size?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, calayer

I'm trying to show a bar graph that goes up and down.
But when I run it, it only updates display when bar graph increases, as if Objective-C is not erasing the previous CALayer's image.

If the CALayer's .frame is set smaller, does it automatically erase the previous image?

Here's how I update it:

```
    [ CATransaction begin ]; 
[CATransaction setValue : ( id ) kCFBooleanTrue forKey : kCATransactionDisableActions]; 
graph_CALayer.frame = CGRectMake( left_x, top_y, width, height );
graph_CALayer.backgroundColor = bar_background_color.CGColor;
[CATransaction commit];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it does not erase previous image.
My frame arguments were wrong.  y coordinate = 0 is at top of my bar graph, which confuses me time again.  To be a better iOS programmer, maybe I should stand on my head.  :-)